# Jenkins on docker is not visible

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have a problem with jenkins on docker. I am using:

```
docker container run -d --name jenkins2 -p 18080:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkinsci/jenkins
```

and I can see under docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                               NAMES
6a39d85b81t1        jenkinsci/jenkins   "/sbin/tini -- /usr/"   21 minutes ago      Up 21 minutes       0.0.0.0:50000->50000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:18080->8080/tcp   jenkins2
```

but under `localhost:18080` jenkins is not found. What did I wrong?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your problem, I ran the same command and am able to access Jenkins. What is your output of `curl http://localhost:18080`?

Comment: Postman response, Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to localhost:18080. It is docker for windows.

Comment: I see, I wonder if this issue may be related? https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/204

Answer (score 0):

The solution is... use `docker is configured to use the default machine with IP 192.168.91.105` I missed this. Sorry, and thanks to everyone for help. :)